# How can i read bzr repository from python script?

Tags: python, bazaar

like getting information about changesets/comments etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you are on Windows, you should consider using the "Python 2.x" installers rather than the standalone installer for Bazaar.  This will install `bzrlib` in Python's site-packages directory, so you don't have to mess around with *%PYTHONPATH%*.  If you have already used the stanadalone installer, you'll need to add *lib/* and *lib/library.zip* from your Bazaar installation directory to the *PYTHONPATH* environment variable.  If you chose the default, this is *C:\Program Files\Bazaar*

Once you can successfully `import bzrlib`, some examples showing how to actually interact with the bzr backend can be found on the [Bazaar wiki](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Integrating_with_Bazaar).

For details, see [Integrating with Bazaar](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.1/developers/integration.html) in the [Bazaar developer documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.1/developers/)

Answer (score 1):

Found: http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrLib