# Is there a way to programatically access a bazaar repository?

Tags: php, python, bazaar

I would like to access a bazaar repository and pull code from it with either a Python or PHP script.

How is this done? Is there a Python module / PEAR library that makes this easy?

If it helps, the repository is on Launchpad.

**Edit:** As mentioned below, running the bazaar commands directly is not an option. Also, an example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [bzrlib](http://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/). Depending on your circumstance you could also just execute the command lines to do this.

Based on the [Integrating with BZR](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Integrating_with_Bazaar) page you might do something like the following to checkout code. You can also [Export](http://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.export.html) code which might be more appropriate:

```
from bzrlib.bzrdir BzrDir

accelerator_tree, source = BzrDir.open_tree_or_branch('http:URL')
source.create_checkout('/tmp/newBzrCheckout', None, True, accelerator_tree)
```

Comment: Executing the commands requires bazaar to be installed on the machine that's accessing the repository - which is not necessarily a possibility.

Comment: A bit more detail about bzrlib here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864789/2865440#2865440

Comment: @George. Is installation of bzrlib also a problem? One way of dealing with this might be to have a machine acting as a 'proxy' returning you a zip file from the LP project. This opens another can of worms though.

Comment: Installing bzr is just as easy as installing bzrlib, so it shouldn't be an issue.  You don't have to install bzr system-wide to use it.

Comment: @Ian: So I could install it on a shared server with a limited account?

Comment: Yeah; try using virtualenv and installing it there.  You need shell access but not root.  If you don't have shell it's still possible, but trickier.

Comment: @Ian: I do indeed have SSH access.